# Witcher 3 PC DLCs taking up too much space on hard drive

Tags: the-witcher-3

ill be quick, downloaded/installed all patches and dlc with no prob. game is working 100%, but all 13 Dlc's are marked as 27gb space each as the game itself on the HDD,making it full .. what i did wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What medium did you get the game on?  Steam?  GoG?

Comment: What does Control Panel/Uninstall Programs say -- it should list the DLCs (I think) separately and have sizes for each.

Comment: just checked the DLC folder in my gog install, its only 560 megs here.  The whole game is roughly 25 gbs

Comment: I can confirm that installing everything via GOG Galaxy doesn't "take" that much space, it takes about the same size as @z' said. Plus, it is a pretty handy tool. Once you install everything you don't even need to use it again if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Are your DLCs located in your Download folder? If so then these can be deleted since installing them means that they were copied into the game's install folder.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to my experience with modding Oblivion -- essentially, a quirk of Windows is that when determining file size, it looks at the folder, rather than the individual files.

Is it possible that the *folder* the DLCs are located in is 27 gBs in total, rather than being individually so huge?